# Python - In what case I can see like this as output "<map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>"

Tags: python, pandas

I am newbie for python programming. I am read one csv using pandas libs.

The code i am using is like that :

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv("C:\\location-of-csv\\sample-csv.csv");
def update_measure(data):
    return data.split('_', 1)[1]

csv_file['UpdatedMeasurement'] = map(update_measure, csv_file['Measurement'])
```

When i was printing the output:

```
print(csv_file.head())
```

Getting values like this

```
  Measurement                   UpdatedMeasurement
0 COL_TOOL_QUALITY             <map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>
1 COL_COMM_STATUS              <map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>
2 COL_SEN_FW_HRTBT_STATUS      <map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>
3 COL_WNL_FW_HRTBT_STATUS      <map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>
4 COL_COMM_STATUS2             <map object at 0x0000025F7E342BA8>
```

Please tell me what went wrong with my code. 
Please refer me to the document where i can find my mistake and wanted to lean it thoroughly, so that i would know what exactly i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in function [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), which is the object you've observed here. This has some advantages when processing large amounts of data, because it will process each item on demand, and not build a list of all results when only a few were of interest. A related effect is that it will use cache better if you have more layers of processing. In Python 2, [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returned a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) instead, and the iterator version was called [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap). Because of this change, some code that previously showed the results might only show the iterator object; the simple way to reproduce the full result is to apply list().

Answer (score 0):

You need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select second lists by `str[1]`:

```
csv_file['UpdatedMeasurement'] = csv_file['Measurement'].str.split('_', 1).str[1]
print (csv_file)
               Measurement   UpdatedMeasurement
0         COL_TOOL_QUALITY         TOOL_QUALITY
1          COL_COMM_STATUS          COMM_STATUS
2  COL_SEN_FW_HRTBT_STATUS  SEN_FW_HRTBT_STATUS
3  COL_WNL_FW_HRTBT_STATUS  WNL_FW_HRTBT_STATUS
4         COL_COMM_STATUS2         COMM_STATUS2
```

If want use custom function (failed if `NaN`s) use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
def update_measure(data):
    return data.split('_', 1)[1]

csv_file['UpdatedMeasurement'] = csv_file['Measurement'].apply(update_measure)
#alternative solution 
#csv_file['UpdatedMeasurement'] = csv_file['Measurement'].apply(update_measure)
#list comprehension solution
#csv_file['UpdatedMeasurement'] = [data.split('_', 1)[1] for data in csv_file['Measurement']]
```